# JAXB Bindings Globally Replace Type with Implementing Class

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am generating code from an XSD using JAXB.  I have an external bindings file that defines the implementation type for one of the XSD types (using the `class` tag/`implClass` attribute).  When I do this, the generated ObjectFactory is modified to return an instance of the specified implementing class.  However, the generated classes still declare members with the generated underlying type.  Is there some way to make all uses of the generated XSD type reference my implementation type instead?

As an example, assume "example.xsd" is as follows:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...>
    <xsd:element name="Root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Member" type="MemberType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="MemberType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Then, I have the following "bindings.xjb" file:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          schemaLocation="example.xsd" node="/xsd:schema" version="2.1">
  <bindings node="./xsd:complexType[@name='MemberType']">
    <class implClass="myNamespace.Member" />
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

After running `xjc` to generate JAXB classes in the above scenario, I get an `ObjectFactory` class that includes the following method:

```
public MemberType createMemberType() {
    return new Member();
}
```

So the factory is correctly generating an instance of my implementation for `MemberType`.  However, the implementation of the generated `Root` class includes:

```
protected List<MemberType> member;
public List<MemberType> getMember() {
    if (member == null) {
        member = new ArrayList<MemberType>();
    }
    return this.member;
}
```

I would instead like the implementation to be:

```
protected List<Member> member;
public List<Member> getMember() {
    if (member == null) {
        member = new ArrayList<Member>();
    }
    return this.member;
}
```

Is there a way to specify that I want to replace `MemberType` with `myNamespace.Member` within "bingings.xjb"?  I would expect the result of `ObjectFactory.createMemberType` to change as well due to this configuration.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, I finally discovered a way to do this.  The following is the working "bindings.xjb" file:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          schemaLocation="example.xsd" node="/xsd:schema" version="2.1">
  <bindings node="./xsd:complexType[@name='MemberType']">
    <class implClass="myNamespace.Member" />
  </bindings>
  <bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Member']">
    <property name="Members">
      <baseType name="myNamespace.Member" />
    </property>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

The generated `ObjectFactory.createMemberType` method is unchanged:

```
public MemberType createMemberType() {
    return new Member();
}
```

However, the generated `Root` class now has the following implementation:

```
protected List<myNamespace.Member> members;
public List<myNamespace.Member> getMembers() {
    if (members == null) {
        members = new ArrayList<myNamespace.Member>();
    }
    return this.members;
}
```

I have verified that the resulting JAXB objects are both marshalled and unmarshalled correctly.